# Ошибка в коде для рассылки через форму на сайте. Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php, ssl, tls, рассылка

Учусь делать сайт, возникла вот такая ошибка. Код предназначен для рассылки на несколько адресов через форму на сайте. Я так понимаю нужен сертификат ssl? можно ли как-то обойтись без него, ну или как исправить эту ошибку? Спасибо.[image: 1][image: 2][image: 3]

Comment: намного лучше будет, если вы код и ошибки прикрепите к вопросу не фото, а текстом с помощью форматирования

Comment: Спасибо, попробую! Я пробовала вставить код, но писало, что 'это похоже на спам'